# How to determine the latest export options chosen?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

Is there any way to determine which file type and export options where last chosen via Menu → Export? E.g. if the user exported as a PDF (print), I would like to obtain the chosen filename, [`ExportFormat.PDF_TYPE`](http://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign11/#ExportFormat.html), or `ExportFormat.INTERACTIVE_PDF` etc.

As a simple example I'd like to write a script the repeats the last export without showing any dialogs, i.e. preform [`app.activeDocument.exportFile`](http://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign11/index.html#Document.html#d1e47047__d1e52237) by obtaining the required parameters first. Note this is only an *example*, a shortcut for this without obtaining the export type and export preference is not actually useful to me...

Comment: Also asked at https://forums.adobe.com/message/8883535#8883535

Comment: ...I _almost_ forgot how frustrating a usual Forum's "I have a different problem, but I'll post it here anyway, now help me!" mentality is.